# Mac m1 installing nodes_modules and sass not working

Tags: npm, nodes, node-sass

I'm trying to install npm on my project, 'npm install' doesnt work.
this is what my term return :

```
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.2 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "c:python27python.exe" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb whichfailed Error: not found: c:python27python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verbwhichfailed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verbwhichfailed     at F (/Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verbwhichfailed     at E (/Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verbwhichfailed     at /Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verbwhichfailed     at /Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verbwhichfailed     at /Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verbwhichfailed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verbwhichfailed  c:python27python.exe Error: not found: c:python27python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verbwhichfailed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verbwhichfailed     at F (/Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verbwhichfailed     at E (/Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verbwhichfailed     at /Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verbwhichfailed     at /Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verbwhichfailed     at /Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verbwhichfailed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verbwhichfailed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verbwhich` failed }
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "c:python27python.exe", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at F (/Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at E (/Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/thibaultvigneron/Documents/Projets/portfolio/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/thibaultvigneron/.npm/_logs/2022-04-05T09_29_43_825Z-debug-0.log`
```

I have installed node v16.14 with nvm.

Comment: Can you provide some more of the output and/or the contents of the log file (which is in /Users/thibaultvigneron/.npm/_logs/2022-04-05T09_29_43_825Z-debug-0.log)

Answer (score 4):

Try [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage your python environment.

#### Install pyenv

```bash
brew update
brew install pyenv
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.profile
```

#### Install python2

```bash
pyenv install 2.7.18
pyenv global system 2.7.18
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the line `Error: Can't find Python executable "c:python27python.exe", you can set the PYTHON env variable.`, you should install [<s>Python for Windows</s>](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

Maybe your Python environment is not well set. Ensure the path to the Python binary is well configured.

Comment: I am on macos ..

Comment: Why are your environment referencing to a Windows executable then? How did you configure Python on your Mac? Can you output the PYTHON env var for debug?

Answer (score 0):

check this out based on your error SS so far I have found this article

https://github.com/sass/embedded-host-node/issues/66

https://developpaper.com/mac-m1-arm-npm-install-error-handling/